# Dagger2 @Nullable annotation with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

From dagger Module:

```
  @Provides @PerMediaSession @Nullable
    MediaControllerCompat provideMediaController(Context appContext, MediaSessionCompat mediaSessionCompat) {
        try {
            return new MediaControllerCompat(appContext, mediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken());
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The place I inject to

```
class PlayerPresenter
@Inject constructor(val fileManager: FileManager,
                    @Nullable val mediaController: MediaControllerCompat?) : PlayerContract.Presenter { <...>
```

I get following compilation error

```
Error:(15, 10) error: android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat is not nullable, 
but is being provided by @Provides @...di.PerMediaSession @android.support.annotation.Nullable android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat 
...di.MediaSessionModule.provideMediaController$app_debug(android.content.Context, android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat)
at:     <...where it is injected...>
```

I've tried to convert dagger module to Kotlin, it that case Dagger see Jetbrains @Nullable annotation, but don't see annotation in constructor class for some reason.

I use Dagger 2.9

Comment: which Dagger library are you using? are you using kapt?

Comment: compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
                                         version is 2.9

Answer (score 0):

Interability with Kotlin is great, it's my inattention.

The problem happened because I provided instance of interface in dagger module, and provides method receives session compat as an argument without Nullable annotation.
Dagger does understand nullable types in Kotlin without any annotations.